# App Crashing when typing in EditText

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-edittext, androiddesignsupport

I have an app with a register fragment where users can register themselves.

When I start typing on any EditText, the app just crashes unusually.

Error Log

```
01-20 22:52:40.942 6164-6164/in.snotes.snotes E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: in.snotes.snotes, PID: 6164
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
    at android.graphics.Canvas.drawText(Canvas.java:1707)
    at android.text.Layout.drawText(Layout.java:396)
    at android.widget.Editor.drawHardwareAccelerated(Editor.java:1735)
    at android.widget.Editor.onDraw(Editor.java:1657)
    at android.widget.TextView.onDraw(TextView.java:5888)
    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:17086)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16068)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3752)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3732)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16031)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3752)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3732)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16031)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3752)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3732)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16031)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3752)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3732)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16031)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3752)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3732)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16031)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3752)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3732)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16031)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3752)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3732)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16031)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3752)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3732)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16031)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.recreateChildDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3752)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchGetDisplayList(ViewGroup.java:3732)
    at android.view.View.updateDisplayListIfDirty(View.java:16031)
    at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateViewTreeDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:657)
    at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.updateRootDisplayList(ThreadedRenderer.java:663)
    at android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw(ThreadedRenderer.java:771)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2808)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2616)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2223)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1258)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6348)
    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:871)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:683)
    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:619)
    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:857)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6123)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:757)
```

This is my register fragment xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="in.snotes.snotes.ui.RegisterFragment">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/register_toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/register_snotes"
    android:textSize="24sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/name_input_layout"
    style="@style/InputStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edt_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/name"
        android:textAllCaps="true" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/email_input_layout"
    style="@style/InputStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edt_email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/email"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/password_input_layout"
    style="@style/InputStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edt_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/password"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/confirm_password_input_label"
    style="@style/InputStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edt_confirm_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/confirm_password"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_register"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:text="@string/register" />
```

And here is my java class

```
public class RegisterFragment extends Fragment {

@BindView(R.id.register_toolbar)
Toolbar registerToolbar;
@BindView(R.id.edt_name)
EditText edtName;
@BindView(R.id.name_input_layout)
TextInputLayout nameInputLayout;
@BindView(R.id.edt_email)
EditText edtEmail;
@BindView(R.id.email_input_layout)
TextInputLayout emailInputLayout;
@BindView(R.id.edt_password)
EditText edtPassword;
@BindView(R.id.password_input_layout)
TextInputLayout passwordInputLayout;
@BindView(R.id.edt_confirm_password)
EditText edtConfirmPassword;
@BindView(R.id.confirm_password_input_label)
TextInputLayout confirmPasswordInputLabel;
@BindView(R.id.btn_register)
Button btnRegister;
Unbinder unbinder;
private RegisterFragmentListener mListener;

public RegisterFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static RegisterFragment newInstance() {
    return new RegisterFragment();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_register, container, false);
    unbinder = ButterKnife.bind(this, view);
    return view;
}


@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof RegisterFragmentListener) {
        mListener = (RegisterFragmentListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement RegisterFragmentListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    unbinder.unbind();
}

@OnClick(R.id.btn_register)
public void registerClicked() {

    invalidateErrorMessages();

    String name = edtName.getText().toString().trim();
    if (name.isEmpty() || TextUtils.isEmpty(name)){
        nameInputLayout.setError("Name cannot be empty");
        return;
    }

    String email = edtEmail.getText().toString().trim();
    if (email.isEmpty() || TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
        emailInputLayout.setError("Email cannot be empty");
        return;
    }
    if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()){
        emailInputLayout.setError("Enter a valid email");
        return;
    }

    String password = edtPassword.getText().toString().trim();
    String confirmPassword = edtConfirmPassword.getText().toString().trim();

    if (password.isEmpty() || TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
        passwordInputLayout.setError("Password cannot be empty");
        return;
    }

    if (confirmPassword.isEmpty() || TextUtils.isEmpty(confirmPassword)){
        confirmPasswordInputLabel.setError("Confirm Password cannot be empty");
        return;
    }

    if (!Objects.equals(password,confirmPassword)){
        passwordInputLayout.setError("Passwords should match");
        confirmPasswordInputLabel.setError("Passwords should match");
        return;
    }

    mListener.register(name,email,password);

}

private void invalidateErrorMessages() {
    nameInputLayout.setError(null);
    emailInputLayout.setError(null);
    passwordInputLayout.setError(null);
    confirmPasswordInputLabel.setError(null);
}

public interface RegisterFragmentListener {
    void register(String name, String email, String password);
}}
```

I have no idea why the app crashes when I start typing that too with an Index Out Of Bounds exception.

Whats wrong? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove `android:textAllCaps="true"` property from `EditText`

`textAllCaps` property is for `TextView` only. You can not use this property for `EditText`.

For `EditText` caps use this code

```
editText.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{new InputFilter.AllCaps()});
```